# self.context.MyModal is not a function in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2

While creating a modal in ionic 2 I am facing this error:

> Error in ./QuizmePage class QuizmePage -  caused by:
>   self.context.MyModal is not a function

can anyone please tell me how to overcome this error.

My code follows:

**quiz.html page**

```
<ion-content padding>
<button ion-button (click)="MyModal()">Share</button>
```

**quiz.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController, NavController, NavParams  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AccModal } from './modal'

@Component({
 selector: 'page-quiz',
 templateUrl: 'quiz.html'
})
export class QuizPage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams ,            public modalCtrl: ModalController ) {

}

MyModal() {
  let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AccModal);
  myModal.present(); 

}

}
```

**modal.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular/index';

 @Component ({
   template: `
    <ion-card class='popover'>
        <ion-card-content>
            Hello
        </ion-card-content>
     </ion-card>
   `
  })
  export class AccModal {

   private dumbData: number;

   constructor(private params: NavParams) {
   this.dumbData= 22;
  }

 }
```

Comment: where is openModal() ? and what is AccModal?

Comment: sorry that is not openModal I have changed into MyModal() I forget to change it now I updated the code.  Can you tell me now what is the problem in my code